# Django firebase authentication without Django authentication framework

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, django-sessions

I have created a app authenticating user directly from google firebase, without any user model in the project. I'm using firebase [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and python [Admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin). The app is in github.

So the idea is to make a custom [login](https://github.com/binoyudayan/django_firebase_authetication/blob/2a84a19374f37a00f4aaff23e741af7c09572c35/firebase_app/views.py#L23) and [logout](https://github.com/binoyudayan/django_firebase_authetication/blob/2a84a19374f37a00f4aaff23e741af7c09572c35/firebase_app/views.py#L62) views. Also a middleware to process the authentication for each requests. Also the user data can be binded as a python object to improve the usability. At the moment, the middleware [logic](https://github.com/binoyudayan/django_firebase_authetication/blob/2a84a19374f37a00f4aaff23e741af7c09572c35/firebase_app/views.py#L55) is there in the home view.

With the current logic, every request has to verify the cookies and which is a network request. As per the firebase documents, verification can be done without network requests.

> Verify session cookies using the Admin SDK verifySessionCookie API. This is a low overhead operation. The public certificates are initially queried and cached until they expire. Session cookie verification can be done with the cached public certificates without any additional network requests.

But I couldn't figure out where the **cached public certificates** and how to use it?

I'm using [firebase web ui](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#starting-the-sign-in-flow) authentication and sending the token to the server and verifying it in the server as per the documents. Is it safe to use the the firebase app config on the browser? Also wanted to have android and iOS apps, so I would like to stick with firebase.

Is it a good idea to proceed with this? How about developing it to a reusable django app? Please share you thought on authentication and probable security flaws with this?

Github project path: https://github.com/binoyudayan/django_firebase_authetication.git

Thank you in advance.